# Wordpress : wp-admin uri connects to online login

Tags: wordpress

I have existing project, and trying to access dashboard to edit, but it goes to online login. So I am not able to login from localhost.

Example :

`http://localhost/projectname/` - shows home page fine.

`http://localhost/projectname/wp-admin` - ( goes to http://example.com/Showcase)

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you need to edit manually via phpmyAdmin, two option_value in options table, `home` and `site_url`.
These two options define the blog url and the path where WordPress are store (if you are running wp from other folder than the root).

Remote entries can look like this :

```
http://example.com/
http://example.com/wp
```

For a local install, they can look like this (depending on your path where files are stored)

```
http://localhost:8888/example.com (if your folder is example.com)
http://localhost:8888/example.com
```

One more thing, you can delete .htaccess to be sure, that there is no redirection set. If you access to the admin go the setting/permalinks and press save to regenerate .htaccess

There a lot a plugin to move login url, take care to remove all entries in the options table from this type of plugin (regenerate permalink will not solve all issue).

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually resetting your plugins (no Dashboard access required). If that resolves the issue, reactivate each one individually until you find the cause.

If that does not resolve the issue, access your server via FTP or SFTP, navigate to /wp-content/themes/ and rename the directory of your currently active theme. This will force the default theme to activate and hopefully rule-out a theme-specific issue (theme functions can interfere like plugins).

Or maybe problem in this...
Which folder did you install wordpress into on your server?
Most of the times it’s either in the main folder or in a /wordpress/ subfolder. In the first case travelmask.us/wp-admin should work, in the latter case travelmask.us/wordpress/wp-admin should work.
If you’ve installed it into any other folder (e.g. /blog/) than that would need to be written in the url as well (i.e. travelmask.us/blog/wp-admin).